# unable to read images inside folder using php within javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a folder and every 10mins images will downloaded from server to a specific folder into my local server and then I have a script that reads the images after images are being downloaded, but unfortunately its not working.

I used ajax to php file to download images from server, here is the code inside php file:

```
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                            $image_name = 'ads-id-'.$row['id'].'.gif';
                            $image_url = 'http://dev.websiteprojectupdates.com/axul-display/assets/ads/'.$image_name;
                            file_put_contents('assets/ads/'.$image_name, file_get_contents($image_url));
}
```

after ajax success it execute this code to read images:

```
var output  =   '<?php $dirname = "assets/ads/"; ?>'
                    output  +=      '<?php $images = glob($dirname."*.gif"); ?>'
                    output  +=      '<?php foreach($images as $image) { ?>'
                    output  +=          '<?php echo '<div class="col-md-12">'; ?>'
                    output  +=              '<?php echo '<div class="card" style="border: 0px;">'; ?>'              
                    output  +=                      '<?php echo '<img class="card-img-top" src="'.$image.'" alt="ads" /><br />'; ?>'            
                    output  +=                  '<?php echo '</div>'; ?>'
                    output  +=          '<?php echo '</div>'; ?>'
                    output  +=      '<?php } ?>';
                $('.sl-ads-holder').append(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do the php part on the php side, you are incorrectly mixing PHP and JavaScript.

First, do the php that you already have, then you want to run the other script as well on this page, after the first.

```
   while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
      $image_name = 'ads-id-'.$row['id'].'.gif';
      $image_url = 'http://dev.websiteprojectupdates.com/axul-display/assets/ads/'.$image_name;
      file_put_contents('assets/ads/'.$image_name, file_get_contents($image_url));
   }

   $dirname = "assets/ads/";
   $images = glob($dirname."*.gif");

   foreach($images as $image): ?>

   <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card" style="border: 0px;">
         <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo $image ?>" alt="ads" /><br />
      </div>
   </div>

   <?php endforeach ?>
```

On your ajax, you then will have the returned data as html that you can append:

```
success: function(response) {
    $('.sl-ads-holder').append(response);
}
```